# How to subtract inventory and sale using MySQL with time stamp

Tags: mysql, sql

**Inventory Table**:

```
StoreNo Date    ProductBarCode  ProductQty
    61  2016-02-28  2017961746012   100
    61  2016-02-29  2017961746012   100
    61  2016-03-01  2017961746012   100
    61  2016-03-02  2017961746012   100
    61  2016-03-03  2017960624045   100
    61  2016-03-04  2017961746012   100
    75  2016-03-04  2017960624045   90
    61  2016-03-05  2017961746012   100
```

**Sale Table**:

```
    StoreNo     Date         ProductBarCode     SaleQty
        61     2016-02-29    2017961746012          8
        75     2016-03-04    2017960624045          0 
        61     2016-03-01    2017961746012          2
        61     2016-03-04    2017961746012         -5
```

**Desired output**:

```
StoreNo  Date      ProductBarCode   ProductQty
    61  2016-02-28  2017961746012   100
    61  2016-02-29  2017961746012   92
    61  2016-03-01  2017961746012   90
    61  2016-03-02  2017961746012   90
    61  2016-03-03  2017960624045   100
    61  2016-03-04  2017961746012   95
    75  2016-03-04  2017960624045   90
    61  2016-03-05  2017961746012   93
```

I want determine the Actual  number by calculating `(INVENTORY + ALL ADDITIONAL PRODUCTS COMING IN) - ALL SOLD PRODUCTS` with time stamp.Inventory was taken once a month .so  i joined with calendar table and show the dates and values.
if i was `subtract from i.qty - s.qty` it will subtract during that day sale alone if i check next day again inventory will showing 100 ..
Can someone suggest?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  i.storeno,i.datee,i.productbarcode,
isnull(i.productqty-(select sum(saleqty) as runningsum from #salestable t where t.date<=i.datee and t.storeno=i.storeno),i.productqty) as tproductqty
  from #inventory i
left join
 #salestable s
 on s.storeno=i.storeno
 and s.productbarcode=i.productbarcode
 and s.date=i.datee
```

**Output:**

```
storeno  datee     productbarcode   productqty
61      2016-02-28  2017961746012   100
61      2016-02-29  2017961746012   92
61      2016-03-01  2017961746012   90
61      2016-03-02  2017961746012   90
61      2016-03-03  2017960624045   90
61      2016-03-04  2017961746012   95
75      2016-03-04  2017960624045   90
61      2016-03-05  2017961746012   95
```

Comment: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 233
Ambiguous column name 'productqty'.Ambiguous column name 'productqty'.                                                                                                  Im getting this error

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.StoreNo,i.Date,i.ProductBarCode,(i.ProductQty-s.ProductQty) AS ProductQty 
FROM Inventory i 
LEFT JOIN Sale s ON i.ProductBarCode=s.ProductBarCode
```

When the value of SaleQty on Sale table is negative this query will add that value to the result. If it is positive it will subtract it.

If you want that in any case the value should be subtracted then use this query

```
SELECT i.StoreNo,i.Date,i.ProductBarCode,(i.ProductQty-ABS(s.ProductQty)) AS ProductQty 
FROM Inventory i 
LEFT JOIN Sale s ON i.ProductBarCode=s.ProductBarCode
```